# Program for Pollard's p-1 algorithm not working properly

Tags: java

I have a program for [Pollard's *p* − 1 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) but it only factors some numbers and gets stuck on others. (I think it gets stuck when both factors are large primes.) Any ideas to fix it?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pollard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an N to factor: ");
        BigInteger N  = input.nextBigInteger();
        BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2");
        BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
        for (int i = 2; i < N.intValue(); i++) {
            BigInteger aToTheIModN  = a.pow(i).mod(N);
            BigInteger temp = aToTheIModN.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(N);
            // if gcd(a^i Mod N, N) is greater than 1 then temp is a factor of N
            if (temp.intValue() > one.intValue()) {
                BigInteger otherFactor = N.divide(temp);
                System.out.println("The factors of N are: " + temp + " and " + otherFactor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pollard-p-1-algorithm/

Comment: Can you provide the numbers that work, and the ones that don’t? Also, be carefull with the intValue function, it only returns the lowest 32 bits and loses information for integers larger than 32 bits…